# How to Put Constant Text inside Edittext which is non editable

Tags: android

I have an Edittext which takes a mobile number when I tap on that EditText it automatically appends 000 for the mobile number code in focus change event of EditText. My Question is if i tap on that EditText it shuold automatically append 000 and when i tap on any other EditText the 000 should disappear and when i again tap that number EditText the 000 again appends and if i type a number beside that 000 and then tries to remove the number then all of the number should remove but 000 should stay in that EditText and if i tap on any other editText then 000 should disappear. In short the number 000 should only be disappeared if i tap on any other EditText.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put all the conditions in the clickListeners of different editTexts , to disapperar set edit text to an empty string.